# Why can I assign null to value of Type "struct Nullable<T>" but not to my struct?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable

I know the mechanism for Nullable Value Types.
However, I am interested in the following:

The Nullable Value Types are working with the struct (from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e)

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct {
    public Nullable(T value) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public bool HasValue {get;}

    public T Value {get;}
}
```

I can use this like

```
Nullable<int> i = null;
```

Now, I create my own Nullable-Struct the same way:

```
public struct MyNullable<T> where T : struct {
    public MyNullable(T value) {
        /* ... */
    }

    public bool HasValue {get;}

    public T Value {get;}
}
```

Why can I not do

```
MyNullable<int> i = null;
```

now?

I know, that values of struct cannot be null - but why can a value of the struct Nullable be null? Where is the mechanism which allows this?

Comment: The compiler has special support for `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: You *can* do `i = default(MyNullable<int>);`  And you might consider doing `struct... { public static readonly MyNullable<T> Null = default(MyNullable<T>); ... }` and then say `i = MyNullable<int>.Null;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where is the mechanism which allows this?

In the C# compiler itself. `Nullable<T>` is a special type with lots of extra rules, including how `null` is handled (comparison and assignment), and how operators are handled (see: "lifted operators").

There is *also* support in the *runtime* for `Nullable<T>`, for special "boxing" rules.

You cannot emulate `Nullable<T>` in your own code, because of these special rules that you can't express.